# What is the reason of an error "Array access, index expected"

Tags: freebasic

I get an error 73 "Array access..." with code:

```
#include "args.bas"

Dim aargs(1) As Args.Arg
Dim args_num As Integer = 0

args_num = Args.ParseArgs(aargs) 'error 73: Array access, index expected, before ')' in 'args_num = Args.ParseArgs(aargs)'
Print args_num
```

`ParseArgs` is:

```
#pragma once

Namespace Args
...
Type CommandGetter As Function(ByVal arg_idx As Long) As String


Function ParseArgs(aargs(Any) As Arg, getcmd As CommandGetter=NULL) As Integer
...
End Function


End Namespace
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question :)

Passing of arrays needs `()`, the correct syntax is:

```
args_num = Args.ParseArgs(aargs())
```